# Split a php array in to two

Tags: php, arrays, split

I have a PHP array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => 24
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 4
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 23
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 0
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [0] => 22
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 6
    )
)
```

with the column [2][3] I want to make a new array from the above array which should be like the following .

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 4
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 0
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 6
    )
)
```

Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this -

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($yourArray as $value) {
    $newArray[] = array($value[2], $value[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
array_map(function($elem) { 
  return array($elem[2], $elem[3]); 
}, $array);
```